# How to correctly define a function like "any"

Tags: haskell

Studying Haskell, i'm trying to code a function `takeIf` that given a condition and a list returns all the list's element that satisfies the condition.

Examples of desired output:

```
takeIf (>0) [] --> []
takeIf (>0) [-1, 0, 1, 2] --> [1,2]
```

I tried this definition:

```
takeIf cond [] = []
takeIf cond (x:xs) = if (cond x) 
                    then x:(takeIf cond xs)
                    else []:(takeIf cond xs)
```

but it doesn't work.

My first question is: I have

```
:t takeIf --> ([a] -> Bool) -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
```

why? Why not:

```
:t takeIf --> (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

How can I get this code to work?

This is the error I get:

[image]

If helpful i'm using `ghci`

Comment: Note that `takeIf` is more commonly known (and already defined) under the name `filter`.

Comment: Yes, like in Scheme..i was trying to understand how to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[]:(takeIf cond xs)
```

Here you're trying to prepend [] as the new first element to the result of `takeIf cond xs`. Since `[]` is a list, GHC infers from that that the result of `takeIf cond xs` must be a list of lists. Since the result of takeIf has the same type as its argument, that means `xs` must also be a list of lists. And since `x` is an element of `xs`, `x` must consequently be a list.

It seems like you intended `[]:` to mean "prepend nothing to the list", but `[]` isn't nothing, it's the empty list. `[] : []`, doesn't give you `[]`, it gives you `[[]]`. Likewise `[] : [1,2,3]` would give you `[[], 1, 2, 3]` - except that that's not well-typed, so what it really gives you is a type error.

If you want to prepend nothing to a list, just don't prepend anything to the list, i.e. just use `someList` instead of `[] : someList`.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Following your instruction I get also an alternative solution: use `[] ++ someList`.

Comment: actually I don't know but why do you want to do `[]++` it's kind of adding 0, which is optimized out (hopefully) by the compiler

Comment: I absolutely agree with you. That is just way to concatenate the empty list with another list, but your proposal is much better.

Answer (score 3):

since sepp2k was faster than me - I just want to add that you might want to have a look at [`filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3afilter) and it's source which is exactly the function you try to reimplement.
Here is the actual source

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter _pred []    = []
filter pred (x:xs)
  | pred x         = x : filter pred xs
  | otherwise      = filter pred xs
```

Comment: +1 For pointing out the function already exists. But also consider that one way of learning is writing suboptimal versions of existing functions :D

Comment: thanks for the +1, IMHO learning by rewriting yourself is one of the most rewarding and annoying things - but afterwards/during the process one should have a look how do the "pro" guys implement the stuff you're trying to achieve. thats why I wanted to add the answer.

Answer (score 0):

An altenative are folds, e.g.

```
filter' f = foldr go [] where 
   go x xs = if f x then x:xs else xs
```